# Call an existing contract function from truffle console

Tags: truffle, truffle-console

Let's suppose an existing Ethereum deployed contract.

I know the deployment Address and i have the contract's source code.

What i want to do is to call a function on this deployed contract from truffle console.

Is it possible and how can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a contract like the one below deployed at address `0x1f2deF1210B4D06B267A64b9888990734Aba7e24`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

contract test {
    string public initialString = "Hello World!";

    function getString() public view returns (string memory) {
        return initialString;
    }
}
```

To create an instance of that contract:

```
truffle(develop)> contract = await test.at('0x1f2deF1210B4D06B267A64b9888990734Aba7e24')
```

To call a function:

```
truffle(develop)> a = await contract.getString()
```

To check the variable directly (if declared as public):

```
truffle(develop)> b = await.contract.initialString()
```

This way, you will have in `a` and `b` the expected values.

Of course you need to point to the right Ethereum network within the `truffle-config.js` file in *networks* section.